# Asking a for a Variable only if is true

Tags: java, project, computer-science

Im doing my first project for my CSE 20 class, i have to code a simple rental car system. Im stuck at the very beginning. I need to ask for the car, # of days, then whether you are a club member or not. If your not the code needs to continue and output the totals, which it does. But if you are a club member it has to ask another question about an executive package then this adds another line to the total ouput. I do not know how to code it to run through completely. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public abstract class Bobcar1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner blah = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Available cars: 1 for Econobox, 2 for Compact, 3 for Standard");
    System.out.print("Please choose the rental car: ");
    int car;
    car = blah.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter the number of rental days: ");
    int day;
    day = blah.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Club member?: 1 for yes, 0 for no: ");
    int re;
    re = blah.nextInt();
    if (re == 1)
        System.out.print("Platinum Executive Package?: 1 for yes, 0 for no: ");
    int pack;
    pack = blah.nextInt();
    if (re == 0) then what do i code here to get the program to run through completely?

    if (car == 1)   {
            int car1;
            car1 = (25 * day);

                    System.out.println("Base: " + day + " day(s) for a Econobox @ $25 per day:      " + "+$" + car1);
                    if (pack == 0 && re == 0)       {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Total Estimate for Rental:                  " + " $" + car1);
                    }
                    if (re == 1 && pack == 0)       {
                            int re1;
                            re1 = (day/5)*25;
                    System.out.println("Club Member Discount:                   " + "-$" + re1);
                            int total1r;
                            total1r = car1 - re1;
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Total Estimate for Rental:                  " + " $" + total1r);
                    }
                    if (pack == 1 && re == 1)       {
                            int pack1;
                            pack1 = (int) (car1*.20);
                    System.out.println("Platinum Executive Package:                 " + "+$" + pack1);     
                            int re1;
                            re1 = (day/5)*25;
                    System.out.println("Club Member Discount:                   " + "-$" + re1);
                            int total1;
                            total1 = car1 + pack1 - re1;
                            System.out.println("Total Estimate for Rental:                  " + " $" + total1);
                    }
    }
    if (car == 2)   {
            int car1;
            car1 = (55 * day);

                    System.out.println("Base: " + day + " day(s) for a Compact @ $55 per day:  " + "+$" + car1);
                    if (pack == 0 && re == 0)       {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Total Estimate for Rental:                  " + " $" + car1);
                    }
                    if (re == 1 && pack == 0)       {
                            int re1;
                            re1 = (day/5)*55;
                    System.out.println("Club Member Discountt:                   " + "-$" + re1);
                            int total1r;
                            total1r = car1 - re1;
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Total Estimate for Rental:                  " + " $" + total1r);
                    }
                    if (pack == 1 && re == 1)       {
                            int pack1;
                            pack1 = (int) (car1* .20);
                    System.out.println("Platinum Executive Package:                 " + "+$" + pack1);     
                            int re1;
                            re1 = (day/5)*55;
                    System.out.println("Club Member Discount:                   " + "-$" + re1);
                            int total1;
                            total1 = car1 + pack1 - re1;
                            System.out.println("Total Estimate for Rental:                  " + " $" + total1);
                    }
    }
    if (car == 3)   {
            int car1;
            car1 = (100 * day);

                    System.out.println("Base: " + day + " day(s) for a Standard @ $100 per day:        " + "+$" + car1);
                    if (pack == 0 && re == 0)       {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Total Estimate for Rental:                  " + " $" + car1);
                    }
                    if (re == 1 && pack == 0)       {
                            int re1;
                            re1 = (day/5)*100;
                    System.out.println("Return Customer Discount:                   " + "-$" + re1);
                            int total1r;
                            total1r = car1 - re1;
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Total Estimate for Rental:                  " + " $" + total1r);
                    }
                    if (pack == 1 && re == 1)       {
                            int pack1;
                            pack1 = (int) (car1*.20);
                    System.out.println("Platinum Executive Package:                 " + "+$" + pack1);     
                            int re1;
                            re1 = (day/5)*100;
                    System.out.println("Club Member Discount:                   " + "-$" + re1);
                            int total1;
                            total1 = car1 + pack1 - re1;
                            System.out.println("Total Estimate for Rental:                  " + " $" + total1);
    }

 }}}}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you would ask a specific question. Any help would be appreciated is a statement. What would you like help with?

Comment: How would i code it to only when there a club member, ask for the platinum package without it just stopping there? When i run it, itll run till then and just stop.

Comment: How asking for *platinum package* is **functionally** different from asking for *club membership*? And you are apparently OK with the latter.

Comment: I only want to ask if they want the platinum package if there a club member if not, it should output a total after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your OP (Original Post) to include the question you posted in your comment.

If all you want to do is modify the code to only ask if they want the platinum package if they specified that they are a club member, then you need to modify your code so that you only read the input from the scanner for that question if you print the question.

In other words, put {} around your if statement block. This is a best practice, even for 1 line statement blocks.

You currently have:

```
...
int re;
re = blah.nextInt();
if (re == 1)
    System.out.print("Platinum Executive Package?: 1 for yes, 0 for no: ");
int pack;
pack = blah.nextInt();
...
```

You could modify your code like this:

```
...
int pack;
int re = blah.nextInt();
if (re == 1) {
    System.out.print("Platinum Executive Package?: 1 for yes, 0 for no: ");
    pack = blah.nextInt();
}
...
```

Comment: Oh alright thank you very much. Im sorry, this is my first attempt at coding and asking for help. So i miss a lot. THanks again.

Comment: If this was the answer you're looking for, please consider marking it as the accepted solution. This is the standard practice for StackExchange sites.